# cifs mounting all files as root owner

Tags: cifs

I am trying to access a win7 machine that has sharing enabled on a folder.  When I mount it on linux it lists all files as -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root

If i sudo i can copy files back and forth but its read only if I dont.

sudo chown [standard_user] * 
on the mounted share does nothing.

This mounts the share as read only (all files are root)
sudo mount -t cifs "//myipaddress/myshare" /home/myuser/mymount/ -o username=myusername,password=mypassword,rw

On the win7 box I have myuser and everyone as 'full control'

how do I mount this share so that I dont have to be root to delete/move files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following. Works fine for me.

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o vers=1.0,username=myuser,pass=mypass "//myipaddress/myshare" /home/myuser/mymount/
```

Comment: obsolete answer, does not work for Ubuntu 21.04

Answer (score 14):

```
mount -t cifs "//myipaddress/myshare" /home/myuser/mymount/ -o username=myusername,password=mypassword,uid=myusername,gid=users
```

Comment: If an answer helps you, accept it by clicking on the small grey tick/check beneath the number on the left hand side of the answer @flashc5 , once you have enough reputation you can upvote too. All this information is in the [tour], reading it will also get you your first badge woo-hoo!

Comment: i alsways do,  it makes you wait so many minutes before you can mark it as the answer

Comment: This worked, but all the files created through the mount are now `-rwxrwxrwx`. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: @RogierLommes I do not think that this is possible on a per file basis (as MS file systems do not support linux file permissions).

Comment: It doesn't show to appropriate owner if I mount an AD share

Comment: obsolete answer, does not work for Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: @jbarlow It still works on my mashine on Ubuntu 21.04. Maybe you encountered another problem.

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't work when you specify `myusername` and `users`, but instead with `1000` and `1000`

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue on Ubuntu 22.04 in 2022. And found the solution here [How to Mount Windows Share on Linux using CIFS](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-mount-cifs-windows-share-on-linux/)

I added below entry in `/etc/fstab` file so as to auto mount the shared folder during boot

`//192.168.x.x/mysharedfolder /home/myubuntuuser/mysharedfolder cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/path-to/.credentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0755`

In the above fstab entry uid and gid is user id and group id of *myubuntuuser*, which can be found using `id` command on terminal. dir_mode and file_mode provide the file/folder permissions during mount.

Answer (score 0):

vi /user/credfile
username=user
password=pass
domain=mydomain.local

vi /etc/fstab
//192.168.86.23/Share /mnt/Share cifs credentials=/user/credfile,_netdev  0  0

mount -a

Answer (score -1):

You have to make sure the mounting target is owned by the user/group first.

#### Change directories ownership

```
sudo chown myusername:mygroupname /mymount/
```

#### Mount it to home dir

```
mkdir ~/mymount
sudo mount /path/to/partition ~/mymount
```

Comment: while this solution is correct, I would advise against blindly changing permissions/ownership of files/directories if you don't know what you're doing

Comment: Answer is not only incorrect, but is missing the required '-R' (recursive) option to chown.